# c++ lib viewer download

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

is there any lib viewer or converter to h files that i can download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are umpteen tools that let you inspect libraries, but very few that generate header files (a library file seldom contains enough information to do that).

Example using Microsoft's toolchain:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib> dumpbin /symbols AclUI.Lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Dump of file AclUI.Lib

File Type: LIBRARY

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00937809 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_ACLUI
002 C0000040 SECT2  notype       Section      | .idata$2
003 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .idata$6
004 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$4
005 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$5
006 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
007 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | ACLUI_NULL_THUNK_DATA

String Table Size = 0x4E bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00937809 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR

String Table Size = 0x1D bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00937809 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | ACLUI_NULL_THUNK_DATA

String Table Size = 0x1B bytes

Summary

`BD .debug$S
      14 .idata$2
      14 .idata$3
       4 .idata$4
       4 .idata$5
       A .idata$6`

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib> _